# Subclass test without regard to type argument

Tags: inheritance, types, f#

If you run:

```
type Car<'T> () = class end
type Mercedes () =
    inherit Car<int> ()
let merc = Mercedes ()
```

and then run each of the following lines, you get the indicated results:

```
merc :? Mercedes        // true
box merc :? Mercedes    // true
merc :? Car<int>        // error FS0193: types not compatible
box merc :? Car<int>    // true
merc :? Car<_>          // error FS0193: types not compatible
box merc :? Car<_>      // false
```

1. See the first four cases. Why do you need to box `merc` for the test against `Car<int>`, but not for the test against `Mercedes`?
2. In the last two cases I'm trying to find something that'll return `true` because `merc` is a `Car`, without regard to the type argument. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your second question, there is no built-in operator for testing whether a value inherits from a class regardless of a type argument. You can check this using reflection by getting the base type of `Mercedes` and comparing its generic type definition with the generic type definition of `Car<_>`:

```
merc.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<Car<_>>
```

In practice, it may be much easier to introduce a non-generic base class though:

```
type Car() = class end
type Car<'T> () = 
    inherit Car()
type Mercedes () =
    inherit Car<int> ()

let merc = Mercedes ()
box merc :? Car
```

To answer your first question, I think the compiler is giving you a hint that the operation is not useful because it will always succeed - so there is no point checking this using `:?`.

If you instead have a value that has a static type of `Car<int>` and you want to check whether it is `Mercedes`, this is alowed, because that is an interesting question to ask:

```
Car<int>() :? Mercedes
```

But checking `Car<obj>() :? Mercedes` is not allowed, because this is statically known to be false.

Comment: I don't think "_operation is not useful because it will always succeed_" is the reason. If it was the reason, it would also apply to `merc ?: Mercedes`

Comment: @FyodorSoikin That's a good point. In that case, I don't think I have a good explanation!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question:

> Why do you need to box `merc` for the test against `Car<int>`, but not for the test against `Mercedes`?

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/#type-symbols-and-operators), the **type test operator** `:?`

> Returns `true` if the value matches the specified type (including if it is a subtype); otherwise, returns `false`

Line 4 `box merc :? Car<int>` succeeds because `box merc` rises the type in the hierarchy up to `object`, the highest type.

Line 3 `merc :? Car<int>` should have return `false` because `Mercedes` > `Car<int>`. Instead, it's not compiling which is a behavior not documented but also not surprising for me as we always know that it cannot be true. Notice that it could have been just a warning, like in C# when we writes `if (true) ...`.

But it's surprising why this behavior is not applied for line 1 `merc :? Mercedes`. It should fail to compile for the same reason of "obviousness". Instead, it's just a warning `FS0067: This type test or cast of a base class into a derived class will always succeed`

**Conclusion:** the *type test operator* is really designed just as a **downcast test operator.** Using it in other cases like to check upcast can be misleading (at compile time) but still safe at runtime.